# How to request a limited no of features in Overpass api?

Tags: openlayers-2, openstreetmap, api

I am using Overpass api to query Building data from OpenStreetMap. the query string is like this

```
(way[building](bbox);node(w););out body;
```

This works really fine (the bounding box is specified by Openlayers).

Now i want to improve it, such that only 10 buildings are returned by the query, to speed up the process. For this i used the query

```
(way[building](bbox);node(w););out 10;
```

but doing this returns only 10 nodes [like here](http://overpass-turbo.eu/?Q=%28%0A%20%20way%28%7B%7Bbbox%7D%7D%29%5Bbuilding%5D;%0A%20%20node%28w%29;%0A%20%20%29;%0Aout%2010;&C=27.7281;85.30042;18&R)

What i want is 10 buildings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is not feasible yet.

See the same question [answer](https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/20472/how-to-request-a-limited-no-of-features-in-overpass-api) from help.openstreetmap.org